# Powershell script from C# error

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to run a `PowerShell` script from my C# program. In the C# file, I have done things like creating the run space to set up everything. When building, the project outputs to a `cshtml` webpage. as of now what I have added to the CS file should have no effect on the webpage.

When we build, we get an error as the webpage pops up:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

This happens even if the only line I added was:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
```

I have tried adding `Nuget` packages, etc with no luck.

Comment: what version of powershell are you running?

Comment: running powershell 4